# event name should have at least 3 parts separated by slash. Parameter name eventName in Asp.Net Core Docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, windows-10, asp.net-core-webapi

I am getting an error as "event name should have at least 3 parts separated by slash. Parameter name eventName" when adding a docker support to my existing Asp.Net Core Web API project.

[image]

Any one faced this issue before? I have already tried reopening my solution and restarted my machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix this error myself, and thought of sharing it here, so that it can be useful to someone else.

The problem was because, one of my colleague deleted the docker-compose file and docker file from my solution to re-enable the Docker support for some reason, and when we were trying to add the Docker support, we got this error.

Even though we deleted the Docker support file from Visual Studio solution, the files were not being deleted from the solution directory. As a fix, you must delete those files manually by going to that directory, after that you will be able to add the Docker support again to your project.

Comment: Thank you for this. I didn't think to check the file explorer to double check.

Answer (score 50):

There is another cause of this. To fix it go to File=>Account Settings in VS and sign in

Comment: This helped my with same issue. Had to re-enter creds and things worked.

Comment: i had this without Docker, I was publishing to a Function App from VS, re-entering credentials fixed it

Comment: This did it for me.

Comment: This is the solution. It worked for me when I was publishing to Azure

Answer (score 3):

For the  "event name should have at least 3 parts separated by slash..."

My work-around: You HAVE to do a **clean**, then a **rebuild all** then a **publish**. The build process in the publish *intermittently* causes a failure.

[EDIT] I have found just doing the clean and then publishing also works. fwiw.

[image: My VS details]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this issue by updating visual studio version

Comment: same here, had to update to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

I deploy to Azure with two different accounts. I did not realize I was logged in to my personal account in Visual Studio when I thought I was logged in to my org account. Swapping to the correct account resolved this cryptic error message for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me re-entering my credentials solved the issue.

I clicked restore, logged in again and didn't follow through (but propably any way to re-enter credential would also work)